# How to play 4096x2304 video on 3840x2160 Samsung UE65HU7500

Tags: ffmpeg, tv, hdtv, high-definition

[To the close voters: TVs are basically tablets now, and similar questions were welcome here in 2012. Please support [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59720/home-theater-audio) and migrate your TV questions if firmware and such are off-topic now.]

I've downloaded some 4K videos from YouTube to a USB stick, but some that are more than 3840 pixels wide, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOAEIMx39-w), won't play on the Samsung UE65HU7500 TV i have here. The TV says the resolution is not supported.

The goal is to have a giant wall-mounted tablet; is there a way to play real 4K videos without connecting another computer? Perhaps by using ffmpeg to convert the files?

Comment: crop the video. or play the next one down , the tv still has upscaling features.

Comment: The next one down (2K, 1440p) is not enough for me up close on a 65" screen.

Comment: This question is still not on topic. Its not about **computer** hardware. If you want to discuss where this might be a better fit, the [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), [Ask Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator), or [http://meta.superuser.com](http://meta.superuser.com/questions) is a better place then editing your question and "talking" to the closed voters.  Besides you already provided the only correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestions, but i doubt those fit better than Area51. A firmware update for the **computer** inside the TV could also provide downscaling.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - The chatrooms were to solved the problem, meta.superuser.com was to discuss if this question is on topic or not.  Your question was in a queue to reopened hence my comment.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand, and have no hope of TV-only questions being answered here anymore, hence my suggestion to visitors of backing the HT&A proposal where old and new questions like these are welcome.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - I don't believe they were ever on question, they might not have been locked, but the description of this website and what is and not on topic has remained pretty nuch the same.

Comment: @Ramhound I've requested an ffmpeg solution so this question is on-topic now.

Comment: Also, [if it has an "update firmware" button, that means installing different software is a normal part of use, so it is a computer.](https://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resized the video to the TV's max resolution, using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html):

```
ffmpeg -i TheWorld.mp4 -s 3840x2160 -acodec copy test.mp4
```

Alternatively, the [scale video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) could be used instead of `-ss`. Provide the value for one axis, and the filter will provide the other while preserving the aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i TheWorld.mp4 -vf scale=3840:-2 -acodec copy test.mp4
```

Apparently, "4K" is a misnomer, as the TV is actually [QFHD](http://www.stuff-review.com/2012-04/what-is-4k-and-qfhd-resolution/):

> QFHD stands for Quad Full High Definition and it’s exactly four times
>   the resolution of 1080p. QFHD or Quad HD measures 3840 x 2160 pixels,
>   and it’s a digital television format with the same widescreen 16:9
>   aspect ratio you are used to watching at home. QFHD is literally like
>   combining four (two-by-two) 1080p TVs together.
>
> Many manufacturers are marketing their QFHD products as being 4K,
>   which has now become a catchall phrase. So if you hear about a 4K TV,
>   the resolution would actually be 3840 x 2160, i.e. Quad HD.